# Skolem Functions on Kunen

Tags: set-theory

I'm studying Kunen's "Introduction to Set Theory" and I can't figure out something.
On the proof of the lemma 5.1 on Chapter 6, the last line states that the set $\{\rho<\omega_1:L(\rho) \text{ is closed under all the } H_{nm}\}$ is c.u.b. and states that this follows from lemma 6.13 from chapter 2.

Lemma 6.13 from chapter 2 states that whenever $\kappa>\omega$ and $\mathscr A$ is a set of less than $\kappa$ finitary functions, then the set $\{\rho < \kappa: \rho \text{ is closed under } \mathscr A \}$ is c.u.b.

Well, it's not exactly the same thing. Can someone tell me how to apply lemma 6.13 in this case?

**Edit:**
$H_{nm}$ are the Skolem functions defined using the functions $En$ in the same book, but I don't think that their definition is relevant to prove that the set above is c.u.b. The important thing is that they are all finitary.

Comment: To those who don't have the book at reach, what is $H_{nm}$?

Comment: Okay, just edited :)

Comment: The standard trick is to use ranks. So, given $H$, define $f$ by $f(\alpha)=\beta$ iff $\beta$ is least that $f''L(\alpha)\subset L(\beta)$.

Comment: Andres, let $C=\{\rho<\omega_1:L(\rho) \text{ is closed under all the } H_{nm}\}$, let $f_{nm}$ like you just defined and let $D=\{\rho<\omega_1:\rho \text{ is closed under all the } f_{nm}\}$.

I'm trying to prove that $C=D$. Let $\alpha \in D$ and $x \in L(\alpha)$. All I know is that for all $\beta \in \alpha$ $H_{nm}''L(\beta) \subset L(\alpha)$, therefore, if $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal and $\alpha=\gamma+1$ and $x \in L(\alpha) \ L(\gamma)$ I don't know how to show that $H_{nm}(x) \in L(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove the following lemma:

> Let $\kappa>\omega$ be regular and suppose $\mathscr A$ is a set of less than $\kappa$ finitary functions, then the set $X=\{\rho < \kappa: L(\rho) \text{ is closed under } \mathscr A \}$ is c.u.b.

It's easy to see that $L(\rho)$ is closed: Suppose $\gamma<\kappa$ is a limit ordinal and suppose $\gamma\cap X$ is unbounded in $\gamma$. We will show that $\gamma \in X$.

Let $f \in \mathscr A$ and $x \in L(\gamma)$. Then $x \in L(\beta)$ for some $\beta < \gamma$. Choose $\alpha < X \cap \gamma$ such that $\alpha>\beta$. Since $x\in L(\beta) \subset L(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ is closed under $f$, we see that $f(\alpha)\in L(\beta) \subset L(\gamma)$. Therefore, $L(\gamma)$ is closed under $\mathscr A$.

Now we will show that $X$ is unbounded in $\kappa$. Let $\omega<\xi<\kappa$. We will see that $\exists \beta \in \kappa\cap X(\xi < \beta)$, which completes the proof. We define $f^n(\xi)\,(n \in \omega)$ by recursion, as follows: we let $f^0(\xi)=\xi$. Suppose we have chosen $f^l(\xi)<\kappa$ for all $l < n+1$ such that $f^i(\xi)<f^j(\xi)$ whenever $i<j$. Let $Cl(L(f^n(\xi)))$ be the closure of $L(f^n(\xi))$ under $\mathscr A$. We know that $|Cl(L(f^n(\xi)))|=|L(f^n(\xi))|=|f^n(\xi)|<\kappa$. Since $\kappa$ is regular, we may pick $f^n(\xi)<\alpha<\kappa$ such that $Cl(L(f^n(\xi)))\subset L(\alpha)$ (looking at the ranks). We let $f^{n+1}(\xi)=\alpha$.

Now we let $f^\omega(\xi)=\bigcup_{n<\omega}f^n(\xi)$. Notice that $f^\omega(\xi)<\kappa$ is a limit ordinal bigger than $\xi$. We now show that $f^\omega(\xi)\in X$.

Let $x \in L(f^\omega(\xi))$ and let $g \in \mathscr A$. Since $f^\omega(\xi)$ is limit, there exists $n<\omega$ such that $x \in L(f^n(\xi))$. By construction, $g(x)\in L(f^{n+1}(\xi))\subset L(f^\omega(\xi))$. $\Box$